# Loading binary data into mysql using load data infile

Tags: mysql

I want to load a binary file into mysql database but I am very confused as loading data is usually done as a string

For example, A 14-bytes file that looks like (in hex)

```
00 01 2C 00 00 FF FF 0A
00 02 2C AB CD EF 00 0A
```

I want to load it in a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable
(
    id smallint unsigned primary key,
    data VARCHAR(4),
);
```

but when I use the following query for loading

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file' into table testtable CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

My question: is there a solution to encode the first two bytes as a `smallint` and store them in `id` column?

Note : 0x2C is the `,` and 0x0A is the `\n` as specified in the query

Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15002729/1254292