# Mysql Error 1064 when using 'SET' keyword in `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` for a blob column

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to insert a table from file using 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'.
I'm able to insert my other tables, but I'm having an issue with a table containing a blob column.

The blob value in file is stored as hex value and each column are separated by `,` character.

I'm following answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038814/import-hex-binary-data-into-mysql)

Mysql server version is 5.6.44

This is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `tx_bin` (
  `hash_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `block_height` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `binary` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hash_id`, `block_height`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this is the sample value in the file I'm using to insert into table

```
4,1,01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff0e0420e7494d017f062f503253482fffffffff0100f2052a010000002321021aeaf2f8638a129a3156fbe7e5ef635226b0bafd495ff03afe2c843d7e3a4b51ac00000000
7,2,01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff0e0432e7494d010e062f503253482fffffffff0100f2052a010000002321038a7f6ef1c8ca0c588aa53fa860128077c9e6c11e6830f4d7ee4e763a56b7718fac00000000
10,3,01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff0e0486e7494d0151062f503253482fffffffff0100f2052a01000000232103f6d9ff4c12959445ca5549c811683bf9c88e637b222dd2e0311154c4c85cf423ac00000000
```

And this is the syntax that I used

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/work/bootstrap/10000/tx_bin' 
INTO TABLE tx_bin FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(hash_id,block_height,@bin) 
SET binary=UNHEX(@bin);
```

The error I'm getting

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'binary=UNHEX(@bin)' at line 1

If I remove the `SET binary` then the insert is successful (but without the binary data).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/work/bootstrap/10000/tx_bin' 
INTO TABLE tx_bin FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(hash_id,block_height,@bin);
```

Then I tried using SET but on other column, it's also successful.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/work/bootstrap/10000/tx_bin' 
INTO TABLE tx_bin FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(hash_id,@height,@bin) 
SET block_height=@height;
```

If I add the blob column again after other column, it also give me the same error

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/work/bootstrap/10000/tx_bin' 
INTO TABLE tx_bin FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(hash_id,@height,@bin) 
SET block_height=@height, binary=UNHEX(@bin);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try quoting `binary` with backticks as you do in your table definition since that word is a mysql keyword?

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. I'm not sure the proper reply in SO, but if you wrote an answer, I'll mark it as answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BINARY` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-B) in MySQL and needs to be quoted when used as a field name.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/work/bootstrap/10000/tx_bin' 
INTO TABLE tx_bin FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(hash_id,block_height,@bin) 
SET `binary`=UNHEX(@bin);
```